Dynamic Colors not working properly in jetpack compose app
I am trying to build an app in jetpack compose.I want to use dynamic colorscheme, however I am facing an issue. when I set dynamicColor: Boolean = true, to true the color changes from predfinded purple to blue, but, that's it, it does not change with my wallpaper color. Even when I've enabled that in my phone setting and my icons and everything change according to that.
Here is code of my Theme.kt file

import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Build
import androidx.compose.foundation.isSystemInDarkTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.darkColorScheme
import androidx.compose.material3.dynamicDarkColorScheme
import androidx.compose.material3.dynamicLightColorScheme
import androidx.compose.material3.lightColorScheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.SideEffect
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.toArgb
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalView
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat

private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    primary = Purple80,
    secondary = PurpleGrey80,
    tertiary = Pink80
)

private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = Purple40,
    secondary = PurpleGrey40,
    tertiary = Pink40

    /* Other default colors to override
    background = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    surface = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    onPrimary = Color.White,
    onSecondary = Color.White,
    onTertiary = Color.White,
    onBackground = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    onSurface = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    */
)

@Composable
fun MyAppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}

I've tried checking if I am targetting right API level, which I am.

Are you testing with an Samsung Device?
With One UI 6.1 or even 6.0 there are some issues.
There are some trick, to go to your dev settings > contrast  and then change it to medium and back.
That will make you device go pink for your app tho.
Found this github issue:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/3924
